# Concurrency problems dealing with sdtout

Tags: c, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

So, I have a process that creates three threads that do their thing, when they do they print the operation on the console.
In the main i have

```
        pthread_create (&window_manager, NULL, (void *) window_manager_receiver_func, (void *)(&args) );
        pthread_create (&send_ack, NULL, (void *) send_ack_func, (void *)(&args) );
        pthread_create (&receiver, NULL, (void *) receiver_func, (void *)(&args) );
        pthread_create (&file_writer, NULL, (void *) file_writer_func, (void *)(&args) );

        pthread_join(window_manager, NULL);
        pthread_join(send_ack, NULL);
        pthread_join(receiver, NULL);
        pthread_join(file_writer, NULL);
```

And in each thread_func i have a `printf("Thread ... starting")` followed by a `fflush(stdout)` to identify if the threads start to run. Problem is not all the threads print that string, I imagine is a syncronization issue right? How can i solve this? I'm in need of threads printing stuff on the console to see if they are doing what are supposed to do.
An idea I'm having is to create another thread that is the only one printing on the console (so there are no concurrency issues on the stdio) and the other threads send messages to that one using named pipes (fifo), is it feasible? Are there better ideas?

Comment: did you try to `fflush(stdout);` after the `printf();`?

Comment: Yes. Every printf call has a fflush following.

Comment: `stdout` is line-buffered by default. You can disable buffering entirely by doing something like [`setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/setvbuf) if you want output without line-breaks to be immediate. Keep in mind this likely will not do exactly what you want. If you want each thread to guarantee a complete msg *per-call* without interleaving you will likely be forced to wrap your own `myprintf` var-arg equivalent using a shared lock (ex; a mutex). From the looks of it, *both* of these in tandem may be what you seek.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
#define mtprintf(...) do {                               \
        char message[1024];                              \
        snprintf(message, sizeof(message), __VA_ARGS__); \
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, message, strlen(message));  \
    } while (0);
```

this way you avoid buffering completely, although you can see that there is a limitation, also AFAIK `printf()` is thread safe in `glibc` but since I don't know which standard c library you are using, this will most likely work.

Comment: I believe I'm using the printf in the stdio.h is that what you mean with standard c library I'm using? <br> Anyway your macro works now "welcome messages" print for all starting threads

Comment: Yes I am, Can be that some of that threads aren't starting at all? (no compiling errors or warning messages at all)

Comment: Aaaand no, I ran the program a few times, sometimes all the threads print the message sometimes only one sometimes only two.

Comment: Are they printing now? also, use `valgrind --tool=helgrind` to detect thread errors.

Comment: @Crysis85 Oh, to check if the thread did start, just check the return value of `pthread_create()`.

Comment: I found out the thread causing troubles, without that all the others start ok and print the message (with the standard printf). Tomorrow I'll try to figure out what's wrong. Thanks for the help